Apply same schema to a fixed set of properties
I have a JSON Schema like this:
{
    "$id": "<some id here>",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "settings": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "setting_1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "setting_2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "setting_3": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "setting_1",
                "setting_2",
                "setting_3"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "settings"
    ]
}

There are many more entries like setting_1, setting_2, etc. Is there a way in which I can apply the config:
{"type": "string"}

to all these properties efficiently? I know we can use $def, but then it will not bring about any considerable reduction in lines, as the common config is just a single key-value pair.
Thank you

EDIT:  use definitions for reusable schema
{
    "$id": "<some id here>",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "settings": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "setting1": { "$ref": "#/definitions/StringType"},
              "setting2": { "$ref": "#/definitions/StringType"}
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
        "settings"
    ],
    "definitions":{
      "StringType": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
}


This will give you an instance
{
  "settings": {
     "setting1": "foo",
     "setting2": "bar"
  }
}


sadly, the properties are not dynamic. in fact, they are fixed and no extra properties should be allowed (hence additionalProperties is also set to false)

Updated answer for you

this does work, but it does not bring about a significant reduction in repetitive work because we are replacing a single config with another single line of config. i was wondering if we can have all these settings in a list and tell jsonschema to apply the config to all these properties. this sounds vague, i know, but i dont know if this is even possible.

JSON Schema is a validation language.  Can you explain a little more how you are trying to use it to "apply the config"?  If you're trying to do something other than validate data, it's likely this is not the thing you're looking for

so what i meant is, i have a long but fixed list of properties, and i would like to have the same configuration for them, like type, format, etc. that's what i meant by "apply the config".. but i see your point, maybe this isnt possible in the spec yet..
